# Extend Django Sites, Site model

Tags: django, django-models

[Django 1.11 Python 3.5 PostgreSQL 9.5]
I make model and relate it with Site through OneToOneField.

```
class SiteExtend(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Стили и Метрики'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Стили и Метрики'

    site = models.OneToOneField(Site, related_name='extending', verbose_name='Сайт', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    style = models.TextField('CSS', null=True, blank=True)
    script = models.TextField('JavaScript', null=True, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField('Активен', default=False)
    playable = models.BooleanField('Играбельный', default=True,
                                   help_text='Будет ли на этом сайте происходить розыгрышь?')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.site.__str__()
```

And unregister and register Site model and my model with admin.StackedInline

```
class SiteExtensionsInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = models.SiteExtend
    can_delete = False


class SiteAdmin(BaseSiteAdmin):
    inlines = (SiteExtensionsInline,)

admin.site.unregister(Site)
admin.site.register(Site, SiteAdmin)
```

When I try add new Site fill only Site inputs(not inline my model) all ok and all save, and if later open to edit this Site and fill inputs my model all ok, but if I try right away fill inputs my inline model I get error:
`Exception Type: IntegrityError at / admin / sites / site / add /
Exception Value: ERROR: the repeated value of the key violates the uniqueness constraint "main_siteextend_site_id_key"
DETAIL: The key "(site_id) = (20)" already exists.`
Maybe someone came acrossed this??

Comment: Isn't it cause you have Site referenced in both models?

Comment: @AndreyShipilov but how? I special relate with One to One

Comment: Not sure, tbh. Where's BaseSiteAdmin coming from?

Comment: @AndreyShipilov from django.contrib.sites.admin import SiteAdmin as BaseSiteAdmin

Comment: Are you trying to choose already existing `SiteExtend` object which related to another site? In this case Django will raise error since it could be only one value for OneToOne field.

Comment: @neverwalkaloner No I try make normal admin interface used django documentation, where u watch trying to choose already existing SiteExtend object which related to another site? It error when I create NEW SITE and NEW related object(SiteExtend) with admin.StackedInline, used admin interface,

Comment: Yeah that's probably not gonna work cause you're referencing an object inline onto itself.

Comment: @AndreyShipilov but I extend User  with like method and all work fine. https://pastebin.com/xhTniabG